# GridLayout spacing problems when using Material Design

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

**SITUATION**

I want to remove the **row spacing** from my GridLayout.

Here is my `main.qml`:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    Root { id: root }

    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    Material.accent: Material.Purple

    visible: true
    title: root.title
    width: 300
    height: 400
    minimumWidth: width
    minimumHeight: height
    maximumWidth: width
    maximumHeight: height

    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        columnSpacing: 0
        rowSpacing: 0
        columns: 4
        rows: 5

        TextField {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.columnSpan: 4
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.row: 0

            padding: 10
            implicitHeight: 70
            readOnly: true
            text: root.input
        }

        CButton {
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.row: 1
            text: "7"
        }
        CButton {
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.row: 1
            text: "8"
        }
        CButton {
            Layout.column: 2
            Layout.row: 1
            text: "9"
        }
        CButton {
            Layout.column: 3
            Layout.row: 1
            text: "/"
        }
        CButton {
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.row: 2
            text: "4"
        }
        CButton {
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.row: 2
            text: "5"
        }
        CButton {
            Layout.column: 2
            Layout.row: 2
            text: "6"
        }
        CButton {
            Layout.column: 3
            Layout.row: 2
            text: "*"
        }
        CButton {
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.row: 3
            text: "1"
        }
        CButton {
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.row: 3
            text: "2"
        }
        CButton {
            Layout.column: 2
            Layout.row: 3
            text: "3"
        }
        CButton {
            Layout.column: 3
            Layout.row: 3
            text: "-"
        }
        CButton {
            Layout.column: 0
            Layout.row: 4
            text: "C"
        }
        CButton {
            Layout.column: 1
            Layout.row: 4
            text: "0"
        }
        CButton {
            Layout.column: 2
            Layout.row: 4
            text: "="
        }
        CButton {
            Layout.column: 3
            Layout.row: 4
            text: "+"
        }
    }
}
```

And here my `CButton.qml`:

```
Button {
    property Root context: root

    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true

    onClicked: {
        if (text == "=")
            context.calculateInput();
        else if (text == "C")
            context.clearInput();
        else
            context.changeInput(text);
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

As you can see in the image, there is a margin between the buttons. When I remove the Material Design from my app, it works, but with Material Design it has row spacing for some reason. Is there a way to fix this behavior or I'm supposed to create my custom design?

NOTE: I don't want to add negative row spacing in my GridLayout to fix this "bug".

[image]

Comment: That's because of the shadow that Material design adds... not really a way around the negative margin. But think before doing that, because the shadow will also have an effect on the button below it (visually)

Comment: @Amfasis can i somehow override the shadow effect values?

Comment: I don't think so, they seem to use some `PaddedRectangle` which implies the padding, but I can't find source for it (think it is build into Material library)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After inspection of the `Button.qml` file from the Qt folder in the Material subfolder, I found the base class have 4 properties: `topInset`, `bottomInset`, `leftInset` and `rightInset`. By setting these you can get the desired effect:

CButton.qml:

```
Button {
    property Root context: root

    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    topInset: 0
    bottomInset: 0

    onClicked: {
        if (text == "=")
            context.calculateInput();
        else if (text == "C")
            context.clearInput();
        else
            context.changeInput(text);
    }
}
```